# undefined method `downcase' for false:FalseClass at puppet agent

Tags: debian, puppet

I have an old puppet running in an ancient debian Lenny. It worked since recently started complaining about an undefined method downcase.

This is Debian Lenny, puppet 2.6.2.

It loads facter, and ends at facter_dot_d

```
Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `downcase' for
false:FalseClass
```

I found a **facter_dod_d.rb** file at /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter but I see no downcase there.

I also tried to download a new puppet agent unsuccessfully. The wheezy version won't install in lenny. I couldn't find a source package to compile it myself.

I did found a facter source at github https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/tree/1.6.x. I tried to download but I can't see how to install it. Running it fails

```
./bin/facter:69:in `require': no such file to load --
facter/application (LoadError)  from ./bin/facter:69
```

I also tried to remove the **facter_dod_d.rb**, but running puppet agent again recreates it and fails.

This is the puppet config file:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
templatedir=$confdir/templates
server=server.domain.foo.bar
environment=legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what happened. Some time ago there was another line in the config file of the client like this:

```
pluginsync = true
```

That made the client download a bunch of plugins from the server. With those files it worked for a long time. Then, I guess, one of those plugins got too new for this old version of the agent. That made it complain about an *undefined method*.

Removing the *pluginsync* line, and also, removing the files in */var/lib/puppet/lib/facter* fixed the issue.

Keep in mind:

- The files in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter must be removed, not just renamed, nor moved to a subdirectory.
- Keep this file, it is required, at least by my puppet agent : /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/util/puppet_settings.rb
- Remove the *pluginsync* option from the *puppet.conf* file in the client.